# How I can add Mixpanel in react native expo project?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, mixpanel

I am getting this below error

```
null is not an object (evaluating RNMixpanel.sharedInstancesWithtoken)
```

How I can setup Mixpanel in expo?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the `expo-mixpanel-analytics` library by `@benawad` with an un-ejected Expo app and it works fine.

https://github.com/benawad/expo-mixpanel-analytics

Segment also has a React Native library and it has a Mixpanel integration.

https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/mobile/react-native/

Answer (score 0):

In expo, you can't use a module with native dependencies if it's not already supported by expo. I will have to first [eject](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) and then install mixpanel according to its docs.